# Unusual [RoutePrefix] behavior in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have two Controllers as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/user/something")]
public class SomethingsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(SomethingsViewModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync([FromUri]int id)
    {
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("v1/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Super Admin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetByIdAsync([FromUri]int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Now by looking at the code above, I'd think that the following two routes are being created:

- v1/user/something/{id}
- v1/user/{id}

But unfortunately, for some reason, that is not the case. I keep getting the following exception message when trying to access one of the above routes:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.
>   The request has found the following matching controller types: MyProject.Api.Controllers.UserController, MyProject.Api.Controllers.SomethingsController

Please help me out in figuring what I might be doing wrong or which small detail am I missing out here.

Comment: In case of Attribute routing, Web API tries to find all the controllers which match a request. If it sees that multiple controllers are able to handle this, then it throws an exception

Comment: @Div I do know that but the issue is that if you look at the above code, multiple controllers shouldn't be able to handle it since there RoutePrefix are different.

Comment: @haseebahmed7 though their route prefix are different their resolved routes match. for example `v1/user/{id}` with match `v1/user/something/{id}` where id parameter arg in the first route will take `something/{id}`. Route prefix and Route attributes combine to create a full route that is added to the route table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094584/multiple-controller-types-with-same-route-prefix-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though their route prefix are different their resolved routes match. for example `v1/user/{id}` will match `v1/user/something/{id}` where `id` parameter arg in the first route will take `something/{id}`.

Route prefix and Route attributes combine to create a full route that is added to the route table.

In a case like this you will need to use constraints in order to better differentiate the routes.

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/user/something")]
public class SomethingsController : ApiController {
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(SomethingsViewModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync([FromUri]int id) { ... }
}

[RoutePrefix("v1/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController {
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Super Admin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetByIdAsync([FromUri]int id) { ... }
}
```

So now with the `int` constraint `something` wont be mistaken for valid parameter for the `UserController.GetByIdAsync` action

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2: Route Constraints](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints)

> **Route Constraints**
>
> Route constraints let you restrict how the parameters in the route
>   template are matched. The general syntax is "{parameter:constraint}".
>   For example:
>
> ```
> [Route("users/{id:int}"]
> public User GetUserById(int id) { ... }
>
> [Route("users/{name}"]
> public User GetUserByName(string name) { ... }
> ```
>
> Here, the first route will only be selected if the "id" segment of the
>   URI is an integer. Otherwise, the second route will be chosen.