# Multiple owin listeners with their own set of controllers, with Autofac for DI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to use multiple in-process owin listeners. Each should have a distinct set of controllers, where they may have the same route handled by a different controller. For instance

> `localhost:1234/api/app/test`   should resolve to `ControllerA`
>
> `localhost:5678/api/app/test`   should resolve to `ControllerB`

controller a, in owin host 1, has route attribute

> `[Route("api/app/test")]`

controller b, in owin host 2, has route attribute

> `[Route("api/app/{*path}")]`

and is used to forward requests to the other owin host.

We are using Autofac for dependency injection. Routes are configured through attribute routing.
autofac requires a line such as

> `builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(ControllerA).Assembly)`

Our OWIN configuration contains:

`var config = ConfigureWebApi();
     // Configure Autofac
     config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
     app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
     app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
     app.UseWebApi(config);`

However when starting two listeners, I need to include both assemblies for controller resolving. This leads to a 'duplicate route' exception:

> `Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can
>   happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested
>   URL.\r\n\r\nThe request has found the following matching controller
>   types:
>   \r\nLib1.Controllers.ControllerA\r\nLib2.Controllers.ControllerB"`

When running the OWIN listeners in separate processes, there are no issues.

I have also tried to use multiple DI containers, one for each OWIN listener, but that conflicts with Web Api 2 as it requires GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver to be set. Which conflicts with the concept of multiple DI containers.

Can someone guide me how to configure such a setup?

Comment: The problem is that even if you don't "use" both controllers, WebApi still checks anything that inherits `ApiController`. You don't have to use `RegisterApiControllers` (you can specify api controllers individually per autofac container) but WebApi still looks at all controllers. Apparently ASPNET core allows you to use multiple matching routes, or you could [write your own attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094584/multiple-controller-types-with-same-route-prefix-asp-net-web-api) for routing constraints, thereby making the routes look different, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use the `OWIN` environment and customize the `HttpControllerSelector`

Using the `OWIN` pipeline you can pass information about the request to a custom   `HttpControllerSelector`. This allows you to be selective about which controllers are used to match which routes.

Of course this is easier said than done. The inner workings of WebAPI with respect to routing are not very transparent - [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) is often the best documentation in this area.

I could not get the `HttpControllerSelector` to fully work, so there's an ugly workaround in `CustomHttpActionSelector`. It may still be sufficient if all you need to do is forward requests from one host to the other.

The end result is:

`GET` to `http://localhost:1234/api/app/test` returns "HellofromAController" (directly invokes AController)

`GET` to `http://localhost:5678/api/app/test` returns "(FromBController): \"HellofromAController\"" (invokes BController, which forwards the request to AController)

See the [full source on github](https://github.com/fkleuver/MultiOwinListener)

I left the logging code as-is in case it's useful, but it's not relevant to the solution.

So without further ado:

**CustomHttpControllerSelector.cs**:

Uses the port-specific OWIN env variable `ApiControllersAssembly` in to filter the controllers.

```
public sealed class CustomHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger;

    static CustomHttpControllerSelector()
    {
        Logger = LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public CustomHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var apiControllerAssembly = request.GetOwinEnvironment()["ApiControllersAssembly"].ToString();
        Logger.Debug($"{nameof(CustomHttpControllerSelector)}: {{{nameof(apiControllerAssembly)}: {apiControllerAssembly}}}");

        var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
        var routeCollectionRoute = routeData.Route as IReadOnlyCollection<IHttpRoute>;
        var newRoutes = new List<IHttpRoute>();
        var newRouteCollectionRoute = new RouteCollectionRoute();
        foreach (var route in routeCollectionRoute)
        {
            var filteredDataTokens = FilterDataTokens(route, apiControllerAssembly);
            if (filteredDataTokens.Count == 2)
            {
                var newRoute = new HttpRoute(route.RouteTemplate, (HttpRouteValueDictionary)route.Defaults, (HttpRouteValueDictionary)route.Constraints, filteredDataTokens);
                newRoutes.Add(newRoute);
            }
        }

        var newRouteDataValues = new HttpRouteValueDictionary();
        foreach (var routeDataKvp in routeData.Values)
        {
            var newRouteDataCollection = new List<IHttpRouteData>();
            var routeDataCollection = routeDataKvp.Value as IEnumerable<IHttpRouteData>;
            if (routeDataCollection != null)
            {
                foreach (var innerRouteData in routeDataCollection)
                {
                    var filteredDataTokens = FilterDataTokens(innerRouteData.Route, apiControllerAssembly);
                    if (filteredDataTokens.Count == 2)
                    {
                        var newInnerRoute = new HttpRoute(innerRouteData.Route.RouteTemplate, (HttpRouteValueDictionary)innerRouteData.Route.Defaults, (HttpRouteValueDictionary)innerRouteData.Route.Constraints, filteredDataTokens);
                        var newInnerRouteData = new HttpRouteData(newInnerRoute, (HttpRouteValueDictionary)innerRouteData.Values);
                        newRouteDataCollection.Add(newInnerRouteData);
                    }
                }
                newRouteDataValues.Add(routeDataKvp.Key, newRouteDataCollection);
            }
            else
            {
                newRouteDataValues.Add(routeDataKvp.Key, routeDataKvp.Value);
            }

            HttpRouteData newRouteData;
            if (newRoutes.Count > 1)
            {
                newRouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(() => newRoutes);
                newRouteData = new HttpRouteData(newRouteCollectionRoute, newRouteDataValues);
            }
            else
            {
                newRouteData = new HttpRouteData(newRoutes[0], newRouteDataValues);
            }
            request.SetRouteData(newRouteData);
        }


        var controllerDescriptor = base.SelectController(request);
        return controllerDescriptor;
    }

    private static HttpRouteValueDictionary FilterDataTokens(IHttpRoute route, string apiControllerAssembly)
    {
        var newDataTokens = new HttpRouteValueDictionary();
        foreach (var dataToken in route.DataTokens)
        {
            var actionDescriptors = dataToken.Value as IEnumerable<HttpActionDescriptor>;
            if (actionDescriptors != null)
            {
                var newActionDescriptors = new List<HttpActionDescriptor>();
                foreach (var actionDescriptor in actionDescriptors)
                {
                    if (actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.Assembly.FullName == apiControllerAssembly)
                    {
                        newActionDescriptors.Add(actionDescriptor);
                    }
                }
                if (newActionDescriptors.Count > 0)
                {
                    newDataTokens.Add(dataToken.Key, newActionDescriptors.ToArray());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                newDataTokens.Add(dataToken.Key, dataToken.Value);
            }
        }
        return newDataTokens;
    }
}
```

**CustomHttpActionSelector.cs**:

You shouldn't need a `CustomHttpActionSelector`, this only exists to work around an issue with the ActionDescriptors for BController. It works as long as BController has only one method, otherwise you'll need to implement some route-specific logic.

```
public sealed class CustomHttpActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger;

    static CustomHttpActionSelector()
    {
        Logger = LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var actionDescriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
            return actionDescriptor;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WarnException(ex.Message, ex);

            IDictionary<string, object> dataTokens;
            var route = controllerContext.Request.GetRouteData().Route;
            var routeCollectionRoute = route as IReadOnlyCollection<IHttpRoute>;
            if (routeCollectionRoute != null)
            {
                dataTokens = routeCollectionRoute
                    .Select(r => r.DataTokens)
                    .SelectMany(dt => dt)
                    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                dataTokens = route.DataTokens;
            }

            var actionDescriptors = dataTokens
                .Select(dt => dt.Value)
                .Where(dt => dt is IEnumerable<HttpActionDescriptor>)
                .Cast<IEnumerable<HttpActionDescriptor>>()
                .SelectMany(r => r)
                .ToList();

            return actionDescriptors.FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```

**Program.cs**:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger;

    static Program()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo
            .LiterateConsole()
            .MinimumLevel.Is(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .CreateLogger();

        Logger = LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new LogRequestModule());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(AController).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(BController).Assembly);

        var container = builder.Build();

        var config = GetHttpConfig();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        var options = new StartOptions();
        options.Urls.Add("http://localhost:1234");
        options.Urls.Add("http://localhost:5678");

        var listener = WebApp.Start(options, app =>
        {
            app.Use((ctx, next) =>
            {
                if (ctx.Request.LocalPort.HasValue)
                {
                    var port = ctx.Request.LocalPort.Value;
                    string apiControllersAssemblyName = null;
                    if (port == 1234)
                    {
                        apiControllersAssemblyName = typeof(AController).Assembly.FullName;
                    }
                    else if (port == 5678)
                    {
                        apiControllersAssemblyName = typeof(BController).Assembly.FullName;
                    }
                    ctx.Set("ApiControllersAssembly", apiControllersAssemblyName);
                    Logger.Info($"{nameof(WebApp)}: Port = {port}, ApiControllersAssembly = {apiControllersAssemblyName}");
                }
                return next();
            });
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        });


        Logger.Info(@"Press [Enter] to exit");

        Console.ReadLine();

        listener.Dispose(); ;
    }


    private static HttpConfiguration GetHttpConfig()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new LogProviderExceptionLogger());
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new CustomHttpControllerSelector(config));
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new CustomHttpActionSelector());

        var traceSource = new TraceSource("LibLog") { Switch = { Level = SourceLevels.All } };
        traceSource.Listeners.Add(new LibLogTraceListener());

        var diag = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        diag.IsVerbose = false;
        diag.TraceSource = traceSource;

        return config;
    }
}
```

**LibA\Controllers\AController.cs**:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/app")]
public class AController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger;
    static AController()
    {
        Logger = LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        Logger.Debug($"{nameof(AController)}: Static Constructor");
    }

    public AController()
    {
        Logger.Debug($"{nameof(AController)}: Constructor");
    }


    [HttpGet, Route("test")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        Logger.Debug($"{nameof(AController)}: Get()");

        return Ok($"Hello from {nameof(AController)}");
    }
}
```

**LibB\Controllers\BController.cs**:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/app")]
public class BController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger;
    static BController()
    {
        Logger = LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        Logger.Debug($"{nameof(BController)}: Static Constructor");
    }

    public BController()
    {
        Logger.Debug($"{nameof(BController)}: Constructor");
    }


    [HttpGet, Route("{*path}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] string path)
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            path = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Split(new[] {"api/app/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
        }
        Logger.Debug($"{nameof(BController)}: Get({path})");

        using (var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1234/api/app/")})
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync(path);
            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Ok($"(From {nameof(BController)}): {content}");
        }
    }
}
```

I might have another go at it when I have more time.

Let me know if you make any progress!