# Use Web API service with the same routes via React Axios

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios

I went toward the answer provided for the question asked in the link below:

[Multiple Controller Types with same Route prefix ASP.NET Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094584/multiple-controller-types-with-same-route-prefix-asp-net-web-api/53078753?noredirect=1#comment93054857_53078753)

To be able to have services within different controllers with the same names but different methods in Asp.net Web API.

I tested it and it worked perfectly with postman application, but when tried to use the same in a React application via Axios, got a network error.

the code to call the service is:

```
return function (dispatch) {    
    var url= ...
    const config = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('AccessToken') } };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(url, config).then((response) => {              

            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCEED_' + param.Caller, payload: response.data })
            resolve(response.data);

        }).catch((error) => {             
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR_' + param.Caller, payload: error })
            reject(error);               
        })
    })
}
```

and the error I get is:

response: undefined
message: "Network Error"
stack: "Error: Network Error↵    at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2195:15)↵ at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1724:14)"

Does anyone know about the solution of my problem?

Comment: can you please provide the code that you are using (with axios) and the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: yes. sure. will add it to the question

Comment: when I call the service, the initial OPTIONS method which is sent toward the server face the error.