# Multiple controller types were found that match the Requested URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have enable attribute routing in route config file and I have declare attribute routing as

```
[RoutePrefix("receive-offer")]
public class ReceiveOfferController : Controller
{
    // GET: ReceiveOffer
    [Route("{destination}-{destinationId}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int destinationId)
    {
        return View();
    }
}


public class DestinationController : Controller
{
    [Route("{country}/{product}-{productId}")]
    public ActionResult Destination(string country, string product, int productId)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

In above two controllers one has static prifix and other has variable prefix 
but I am getting Multiple controller types were found that match the URL error from these two controller.

What is wrong in this routing pattern.

Comment: can you show the URL ?

Comment: url will be like

(domain/receive-offer/new york-1)///////////
(domain/usa/new york-1 )

in above two url usa can be replace with any other country where as receive-offer is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens when the attribute route matches multiple route you can look at this [Multiple controller types were found that match the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21415107/5671377). so when you enter `domain/receive-offer/new york-1` it matches the first Route and also the second URL because it will consider `receive-offer` as a country so to resolve this we can use [Route Constraints](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)
 to specify the values of routes so your route will be

```
 [RoutePrefix("receive-offer")]
    public class ReceiveOfferController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ReceiveOffer
        [Route("{destination}-{destinationId:int}")]
        public ActionResult Index(int destinationId)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }


    public class DestinationController : Controller
    {
        [Route("{country:alpha}/{product}-{productId:int}")]
        public ActionResult Destination(string country, string product, int productId)
        {
            return View();
        }
     }
```

since `destinationId` and `productId` will be of type `int` and `country` will be `alphabet` but keep in mind that if you add spaces in country name the route will not work so you will have to apply `regax` or you can remove spaces between the country name like `HongKong`

Comment: Could you please justify the purpose of :alpha after country in DestinationController route. Or any reference that I can look for

Comment: @Bhuban its called routing constrain means specify the type of the value in route and here alpha means alphabet characters (a-z, A-Z). you can read [attribute-routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) section Route Constraints

Comment: the reason why i used it to make route a bit unique because `receive-offer` is a string and matches route `{country}` so by adding alpha `{country:alpha}` means it will not contain any special character like `-`

Comment: Thank you @Usman 

my above requirement is fulfilled but now I got another issue. In a controller where I don't want attribute routing and want to execute index action just by domain/controller it is executing DestinationController index actions since domain/{country} matched with domain/{controller}

how should I handle this one.

Comment: @Bhuban you can name index   `[Route("Destination")]`

Comment: sorry I didn't understand properly. Where should I put that route in?

Comment: above the index action of DestinationController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142531/discussion-between-bhuban-and-usman).