# Multiple controller types were found that match the URL Error MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, routes, attributes

Before I ask a question I should say that; All routes have been added to the controllers by `Route` attribute. It's not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414448/multiple-controller-types-were-found-that-match-the-url-this-can-happen-if-attr) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578963/multiple-controller-types-were-found-that-match-the-requested-url). Because ID parameter (integer type) is passed to the two different functions in this case.

There are two classes and two functions that all seperated in different class. `HomeController.AppPage` and `BlogController.Detail` functions conflicts when this page `localhost:11111/Blog/this-is-blog-title/1` is navigated. I want to run Second One as I stated below.

In the Second One, `Blog` segment must be stable in the beginning of the route. I don't want to change or remove.

Thank you for your suggestion and help.

**First One**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
    [Route("{title}/{ID}")]              //  -> No problem with this
    [Route("{title1}/{title2}/{ID}")]    //  -> Conflicting attribute
    public ActionResult AppPage(int ID)
    {
        // Some Code
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Second One**

```
public class BlogController : BaseController
    [Route("Blog/{title}/{ID}")]              //  -> Conflicting attribute
    public ActionResult Detail(int ID)
    {
        // Some Code
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding order parameter to the route attribute so that the Blog route takes precedence over the title1 route

By default, all defined routes have an Order value of 0 and routes are processed from lowest to highest

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
    [Route("{title}/{ID}")]              //  -> No problem with this
    [Route("{title1}/{title2}/{ID}", Order = 2)]    
    public ActionResult AppPage(int ID)
    {
        // Some Code
        return View();
    }
}

public class BlogController : BaseController
    [Route("Blog/{title}/{ID}", Order = 1)]             
    public ActionResult Detail(int ID)
    {
        // Some Code
        return View();
    }
}
```

if this did not work you can just list them in the RouteConfig.cs file and write the Blog route before the title1 route

you can read this article for more info

http://rion.io/2015/11/13/understanding-routing-precedence-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: it didn't work. still two functions conflicts. actually, I do not want to list them all in web.config. I try to wright an view engine

Comment: in the route.config not web.config

Comment: Do you mean RouteConfig.cs ?